# Missing vertices while mesh visible, but still able to select them and edit

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, vertices

Don't know what I hit, but I know it is not "H" or Tab. I'm still in Edit mode and the mesh is still visible and I can select a general area and it will select the vertex of that area to be edited. Tried the 1, 2, and 3 keys, but none show on screen for me to select. Can anyone Explain this

Comment: Hello, could you please show a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

Shift + Alt + Z toggles Overlays, which includes the wireframe display in edit mode. There's a button for it in the top right of your viewport.

[image: Show Overlays]